# Combining AND and OR conditions in SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to combine `AND` and `OR` syntaxes with `SELECT`, but it won't show me the data.

`$cel` can be a number or empty, `$ruta` and `$jornada` to be assigned

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, 
    "SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        registros_tty651
    WHERE
        (cel = '$cel' OR cel = '')
            AND ruta = '$ruta'
            AND jornada = '$jornada'
    ORDER BY fecha_r DESC;");
```

Comment: `NULL != ''`, use `OR cel IS NULL`

Comment: @bato3 I think Andres means an empty string. What I am worried about is that he says: "'ruta' and 'jornada' to be assigneded". Apart from the spelling error, it seems like he is trying to assign values and expects them to be inserted in the database. That's not how a SELECT works.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, 
"SELECT 
    *
FROM
    registros_tty651
WHERE
    (cel = '$cel' OR cel IS NULL)
        AND (ruta = '$ruta'
        AND jornada = '$jornada')
ORDER BY fecha_r DESC;");
```